# Log in from iOS app

Tags: rest, api, https, software-design

I have a website and an iOS app and I want it to be possible to login in the iOS app.

But I want the same users both at the website and in the iOS app. My approach will be to create an API at the website and then use requests from the app to the website.

But is it safe to create a API that takes a POST request and then send what the user inputs in the iOS app to the API and then send a request back to the iOS, telling it whether the login was successful.

Isn't it potentially dangerous to send unencrypted like this?

Comment: Make sure your API requests are on `https` By doing so your requests are encrypted and ideally should not be visible for others in plain text.

Comment: iOS by default will block all the requests made via HTTP. If you wanted to use HTTP, you would have had to explicitly allow your HTTP service in info.plist

Comment: Also I think your question will be more suited to Software Engineering SE, not here.

Comment: @NSNoob when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Aha didn't know that. Will do in future. I assumed that OP will delete the post here and take it over to SESE.

Answer (score 2):

You should certainly be using Https for this. This way all communication is encrypted, and anybody snooping on messages won't be able to see what's being sent over. This would require you to run your website of port 443, and preferably also use a certificate to verify your identity. This can be done using either paid or free services, such as let's encrypt. Assuming you're using expres, you can look at [this](https://git.daplie.com/Daplie/greenlock-express/tree/master), which I'm using for personal stuff.

As for the the authentication itself, I would use JWT (JSON Web Tokens). This requires a user to give you a username and password, and once these are verified, you send back a token which has used data encoded in it. You can look at [this](https://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/) for a very simple guide.

Finally, make sure that passwords in the database are stored salted and hashed.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your website login page in web view from iOS application.

1. When user tap on Login button Call API to server with vendor id.
   you can find vendor id from [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor), and open web view
2. Open web login page in web view with Done buttons on top navigation bar.on web view user can login / register or do any action
3. when user press done after login. call API again with same vendor id to check is user login into web from mobile. and send response according.

I Hope it will help you.

Comment: Re #2. How will he get the response of login request if he displays the login page of web in WebView instead of calling a REST API from native VC?

Comment: Re #3. Why should he want to know the user's client config? He should send just JSON via REST API and client should consume it and display it in whatever form the OP wants.

Comment: Re #1: Where exactly does "Vendor Id" come into this? Who upvoted this!

Comment: And how exactly does this answer the question that whether the OP should use HTTP or HTTPS request for his authentication service?\

Comment: Re #1 we send unique id to sever when we prepare for login. Re #2 we place done button on navigation controller. after login web page show message only login successfully.user have to press done button. Re #3 on press done we call server with same unique id for check user is login or not, on get response we close web view and do action according response.

Comment: His userId is unique! You don't need any other unique id to identify him. `we place done button on navigation controller. after login web page show message only login successfully.user have to press done button.` You are joking right? You don't get to know what is happening inside the UIWebView other than the basic defined delegates which do not let you know the state of internal interaction between user and web.  How will you know that user pressing "Done" is actually logged in? Actually I am done here. Your theories are wrong mate

Comment: I did't says put done button inside web view. put it on top navigation bar. for your understanding I will make one demo and share with you.Thank you